# I recently installed angular using npm install -g @angular/cli command.When i check the angular is installed or not using ng-v cmd nothing is shown

Tags: angular

[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIodQ.png)I recently installed  angular using npm install -g @angular/cli command. But when i try to check angular is installed successfully or not using ng-v command it shows no command found. Even i added C:\Users\Prem\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin to path variable. Kindly help me with that.

[paht variable set in environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Htnkf.png)

Comment: ng --version is the command what you should run to check current installed the version of angular-cli. if it shows you the version then it is installed properly

Comment: Thank you akshay when i try to check with ng --version i got the angular cli. But when i try to execute the ng-v command it did n't show anything. i saw lot tutorials they are using ng -v to check angular is installed or not . Is there any difference between  ng-v and ng-version? once again thank you i can solve the problem.

Comment: ng -v tells you:

    What's the globally installed version of @angular/cli

Comment: just check if node is installed properly. run command node -v

Comment: ng-v is not an available command. For more detailed help run "ng [command name] --help" in your command prompt

Answer (score 1):

to check angular cli version you can use:

```
ng --version
```

in short you can use:

```
ng v
```